# Easy way to get gcc and make in OSX

Tags: macos, perl, xcode, gcc, cpan

I want to install a few CPAN modules in OSX.

It filed since the module I want requires make and gcc to be installed. A quick google on the subject tells me that I need to install "Apple developer tools".

Do I really have to install the entire Xcode package (it's a 3GB download) just to get make and gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the easiest way.

Note that you might not need to download it - some Macs come with a Developer Tools CD, or a developer tools package on one of your install DVDs (usually the second one, with the bundled applications).

Comment: I have a Macbook Air - It came with a restore-ssd, nothing else.

Comment: Have you had a look on there? It's the equivalent of the install DVDs, and I'd be surprised if the dev tools weren't on there somewhere. On the DVDs at least there's usually a package in the root or an "additional software" folder - I see no reason that they wouldn't be on there somewhere.

Comment: And the installer might be on the hard drive already, I've seen that on a few Macs. Look in the Application folder for something that looks like developer and see if there is an installer inside.

Comment: This is slightly orthogonal to this question, but for future Googlers. The Xcode installer bundles together a bunch of (smaller) .pkg packages. In theory, you should be able to open Xcode and install only what you really want from it. See this link, for example, https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Xcode